# Do questions about video game soundtracks belong in Music Fans, or Arqade?

Tags: discussion

Do questions about video game soundtracks belong here? I'm just curious as I do have a few  questions about various games and their OSTs. Would it be considered a video game question or a music question?

Comment: Music related questions appear to be [off-topic][1] at Arqade.



  [1]: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/lets-get-rid-of-music-once-and-for-all

Comment: @pacoverflow That says nothing at all about topicality, it was part of a tag cleanup.  The linked question in that post is off-topic due to being about identifying music -- the converse, [identifying a game from music](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9816/6066), is on-topic.  I think the scope of acceptable music-related questions there is small, but it's not nonexistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is entirely about the music, then it would be on-topic here.

If the question relates, in a direct way, to the game, then it should probably be asked on Arqade. Note that I'm not necessarily saying it would be off-topic here.

There are a number of sites that overlap with other sites (Science Fiction with Movies, Space Exploration with Astronomy, etc) and it is often up to the *asker* to decide which site will give them the best answer(s). If the question is on-topic on the site where it was originally asked, SE guidelines are to leave the question there, even if (in the judgement of some people) it would be better elsewhere.

Comment: "In any way" is far too restrictive a reason to ban a music-related question here.  Also see my comment above -- Arqade has a very limited scope when it comes to music-related questions.